# Deploy standalone PHP/MySQL applications

Tags: php, mysql, apache, deployment, installation

I have been looking for a solution that would allow me to deploy PHP applications on Macs and Windows. I've been developing online applications but would like them to be offline applications as well but that would require that Apache/PHP/MySQL be installed on their platforms as well. I've set up WAMP and it was NOT that easy. Lots of configurations were needed. I wonder if there is a way to install easily, something that a person can just click "Install" and it's all done. I don't want the packages to install mySQL manager or anything else - just php/apache/mysql... no extras.

Comment: Are you looking for something like an install-shield wizard for php Applications. One which would also install the apache/php/mysql cocktail as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would be simple enough, but have you looked at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You my think about to build a PHP Desktop Application with PHP-GTK and sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Try [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). Just don't bind MySQL and Apache to their default ports. (3306 and 80). Or better when it comes to standalone application deployments, use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-GTK supplies a distribution that is easy to package and redeploy using NSIS. You should be able to use the gtkHTML control to display the HTML output without too much trouble.

This article [here](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/54825.aspx) shows you how to package a simple PHP-GTK app with NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp, copy your wamp folder to the client's sytem as it is on your system, then install wamp server, when it asks if you want to install to that existing folder, say yes, that way all the configurations will be intact. but you'd have to delete other projects from your www folder so that only the client's project is there.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows case the following will be helpful:

[PhpDock](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm)

PhpDock is a deployment platform for PHP applications.

PhpDock enables you to deploy any PHP web application as a Stand Alone Windows Desktop application w/o any changes in the code.